# How to get an event series upcoming date with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

**[Goal]**

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve the upcoming date of an existing event series that the attendees are required to join. For context, the event was created by another user, however, I am part of the event as well (if that matters).

With this date, I want to be able to use it for something else, to which it would be referring to the upcoming event (series).

**[Issue]**

I tried using the getEventSeriesById method as I was able to find the event ID by using the below code, however, there doesn't seems to be an option to retrieve dates or time from that object.

```js
Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode("long string")).getDataAsString();
```

I also tried using the getEvents method, but it doesn't seem possible to get information about an event that is a series.

**[Question]**

Would there be some kind of workaround or am I completely missing the point on how to utilize the CalendarApp?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The calendar event was created under a Google Workspace account (like the event is part of your organization/ domain) or was it created by a Gmail account ? There could be an option to get the information of that event if you are the Super Admin of your organization utilizing event.list

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz Thank you for responding! I don't think I get get a Super Admin access, so I'll take this as we can't get this info. Really appreciate your help!